# How to get next td value in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

New to Python and am trying to use BeautifulSoup to pull the "ETH Balance" from the an etherscan.com webpage with this code:

```
import bs4, requests

res = requests.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0x93673eeed88fda9423b8037374164383df54aec1')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
ethBal = soup.find("td", text="ETH Balance").find_next("td").text

print('The ETH blance is '+ ethBal)
```

However I keep getting and error that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tfountain/Desktop/python_work/c2.py", line 7, in <module>
    ethBal = soup.find("td", text="ETH Balance").find_next("td").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'
```

Where am I going wrong and what would be the best way to get the ETH Balance?

Comment: `soup.find("td", text="ETH Balance")` is returning none. That means it found nothing in that search. It could be created by js, in which case you need to use dryscrape or selenium. Or maybe you just wrote it wrong

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 - The webpage still displays a "0" value, and since I will be using this code to check multiple address values some of them will non-zero values. For example updating the url to https://etherscan.io/address/0x5593b2b8dc63d0ed68aa8f885707b2dc5787e391 still returns the same error message even though there is a non zero "ETH Balance".

Comment: Can you post enough of `res.text` so that the example contains what you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at the page source, the HTML is:

```
<td>ETH Balance:
</td>
<td>
0 Ether
</td>
```

You're searching for `text='ETH Balance'`. But the text is `ETH Balance:` with a newline at the end.

So, using this:

```
eth_bal = soup.find('td', text='ETH Balance:\n').find_next('td').text.strip()
print(eth_bal)
# prints '0 Ether'
```

Comment: That works but where exactly did you see the new line at the end? When I looked at the source code all I see is: 
`code`
<tr>
<td>ETH Balance:
</td>
`code`

I don't see any \n or <br>

Comment: The closing `</td>` tag is located on the next line which implies there's a `\n` character present.

Comment: Would most other closing tags such as </tr> or others imply the same thing?

Comment: It'll matter only if you want to find them using `text='...'`. And yes, if the closing tag is immediately after the text but on a newline like in the html I've pasted above, there must be a `\n` present. You can always check that by trial and error.

Comment: `eth_bal.split()[0]`

Comment: Use `find_next_sibling` instant of `find_next` in Python 3+

Answer (score 0):

I used regex to find the `td` that contains the word 'Ether' and just parsed that tag.

Code:

```
import bs4, requests, re

res = requests.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0x93673eeed88fda9423b8037374164383df54aec1')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
ethBal = soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Ether')).text

print('The ETH blance is '+ ethBal)
```

Output:

```
The ETH blance is 
0 Ether
```